# Set While loop in FPDF

Tags: php, html, fpdf

This is code is using to generate pdf file. I using $html to do the table and will display in pdf file. But now if insert the while loop in the $html, the output is the php code and got some error.  I confusing the single quotes to closing the code.

```
$html='<br><br><br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Product Name</td>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Product Price</td>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Product Quantity</td>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Total Price</td>
        </tr>
    //Here
    </table>`
    <br>
 <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Order Date</td>
            <td width="600">'.$row['Order_Date'].'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Tracking ID</td>
            <td width="600">'.$row['Tracking_ID'].'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Recipient</td>
            <td width="600">'.$row['Tracking_Recipient'].'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Phone Number</td>
            <td width="600">'.$row['Tracking_PhoneNumber'].'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Address</td>
            <td width="600">'.$row['Tracking_Address'].'</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#D0D0FF">Bank</td>
            <td width="600">'.$row['Bank'].'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
```

//While loop

[image: While loop]